# How to stop my do-while loop

Tags: java, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Qty_Of_Musicians_With_Details {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variables
        String nameMember = "";
        String lastName ="";
        String instrument = "";
        String member_LastName = "";    
        String member_Instrument = "";  
        String member_FirstName = "";   
        int qty_OfMember;
        String musician_FirstName = "";
        String musician_LastName = "";
        String musician_Instrument = "" ;

        //my scanner
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("input number members");
        //read and store user input
        qty_OfMember = userInput.nextInt();

        if(qty_OfMember<=8){
            do{
                //Using FOR LOOP
                for(int i =1;i<=qtyOfMember;i++){
                    //ask for member Full Name
                    System.out.println("enter member# "+i+" full name");

                    //read and store firstname
                    member_FirstName= userInput.next();
                    musician_FirstName = member_FirstName ;

                    //read and store lastname
                    member_LastName = userInput.next();
                    musician_LastName=member_LastName;

                    //Ask for member instrument
                    System.out.println("member instrument");

                    //Read and store member instrument
                    member_Instrument=userInput.next();
                    musician_Instrument=member_Instrument;


                    //print out members names,last_names and instruments  
                    System.out.println(i +"first_name: "+musician_First Name+"\n Last name: "+musician_LastName "\n instrument: "+ musician_Instrument s"\n" );
                }
            //here is the problem,donno how to stop it
            //if user input qty Members == 3

            // after asking each member details loop should stop
            }while(??????????????????????????????????????????????????); 

        }
        else{System.out.println("Sorry but studio can accept max 8 musicians");}

        //System.out.println("name: "+ member1_Name +" Last_name: "+ member_Name" instrument: "+ member_Instrument);

        //closing Scanner
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

> this program is asking for qty of musicians and each musician full name and instrument that he is playing then display each musician details well 
>   It should be something simple I tried:(qty OfMember==qty Member);

Comment: you can use either do while loop or the for loop, not both, to do one iteration..

Comment: remove your do while you already have a for loop

Comment: If you're unsure about loop types, use the infinite loop ``while(true){}`` with proper ``break``s and ``continue``s where needed. Much better than ``while(x){}`` and ``do{} while(x);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*here is a simple one...* **only minor changes to your code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Qty_Of_Musicians_With_Details {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variables
        int qty_OfMember;

        //my scanner
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("input number members");
        //read and store user input
        qty_OfMember = userInput.nextInt();

        if (qty_OfMember <= 8) {
            String[] musician_FirstName = new String[qty_OfMember];
            String[] musician_LastName = new String[qty_OfMember];
            String[] musician_Instrument = new String[qty_OfMember];
            //Using FOR LOOP
            for (int i = 0; i < qty_OfMember; i++) {
                //ask for member Full Name
                System.out.println("enter member# " + i + " full name");
                //read and store firstname
                musician_FirstName[i] = userInput.next();
                //read and store lastname
                musician_LastName[i] = userInput.next();
                //Ask for member instrument
                System.out.println("member instrument");
                //Read and store member instrument
                musician_Instrument[i] = userInput.next();
            }

            //print out members names,last_names and instruments  
            System.out.println("\n\n----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Details");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < qty_OfMember; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + 1 + "\nfirst name: " + musician_FirstName[i] + "\nLast name: " + musician_LastName[i] + "\ninstrument: " + musician_Instrument[i] + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry but studio can accept max 8 musicians");
        }
        //closing Scanner
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Konstantin F just remove the do-while loop. Use a for loop to get the inputs and another to print the details. I have posted my answer, so you can get that. Feel free to ask anything.